# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When i try to do "php artisan migrate" i get this:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

[PDOException]
  could not find driver

I have 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1 versions of php.

I noticed that i have a pdo_mysql.dll at 5.6 folder, i tried to make a copy into 7.0 folder but it didn't work.

Comment: I believe that you need to install a new php_pdo_mysql for PHP 7.

Comment: YUP, i was trying with apt-get install php-mysql but with apt-get install php7.0-mysql IT WORKS.  I'm still getting the warnings but I can finally do the migrations

Comment: `.dll` on linux? It should be looking for `/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so` check your php.ini file for wrong type.

Comment: check in your `/etc/php.d` directory and see where this `.dll` is being called (`grep '.dll' /etc/php.d/* `)